# Toggling view modes of Views results with Display Suite

Tags: 7, views, display-suite

I asked a similar question about a month or so ago, and the answer was to use the Views Modes module.  That module required the PURL module.  The problem is the PURL module leaves parameters on your URL all over the site, and have not figured out a way to turn it off.  Others have posted a support issue and it goes ignored.

So, I'm back to the drawing board.  I have nodes that are rendered, using view modes defined in Display Suite.  Is there a way I can toggle between view modes in Views?  What I'm really trying to do is provide a bunch of filter checkboxes, along with the ability to toggle between view modes, but I need to find a solution for the view modes first.

Is there a module that makes this easy, or do I need to write some code.  If I do need to write some code, how should I approach it?

Comment: Do you mean if you display 3 nodes in a view then you want to show 2 of them with view mode A and the 3rd with view mode B ? Depending on a field value in the node?

Comment: Should the view mode depend on a field value or other entity property, or should it depend on the position in the view? (e.g. zebra striping). That's an important distinction.

Comment: No, they all would display in the same view mode.  I want the toggle functionality that you find at the top right of a lot of sites, where you can, for example, switch between a grid view and a list view of the results.

Comment: It would, from the UI standpoint, depend on if they click an icon that determines the view modes of the results.

Comment: Then I would make it two separate Views displays. And some mechanic to switch between them. Either two separate urls, or some ajax magic.

Comment: @donquixote - that's exactly what I'm trying to figure out.  If I just know where to start, and maybe the general approach, then that's good enough for me, and I can come back and post my code.

Comment: Or, if there was a way I could signal all my nodes in the result (rendered by Display Suite) to toggle on their own, i.e., independent of the view, then that would be just as good.

Comment: Is this a "page" view? And does it have arguments / contextual filters?

Comment: This is a page view, and arguments for filters.  I have a lot of filter options that require checkboxes, so I'm going to use Better Exposed Filters.

Comment: Do you have exposed filters or contextual filters or both? does your url have wildcards? big difference for a solution I am going to propose.

Comment: I do have an exposed filter now, and have not yet implemented Better Exposded Filters.  I am not using any contextual filters.  There is no URL wildcard currently.  This would only change if Better Exposed Filters requires it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution that I use sometimes.

1. Create a content type with one or more multiple-value [block reference](http://drupal.org/project/blockreference) fields.
   This is like a "cheap" version of panels..
2. Create your views displays as blocks. One for each version.
3. Create a custom module to define a block that acts as the "switcher" between the two. Put some dummy content for now.
4. Create two nodes with the block reference.

   - One that has the switcher and the Views display A.
   - One that has the switcher and the Views display B.
5. Set url aliases for both nodes.
6. Flesh out the "switcher" block. E.g. make it keep the url query parameters. Make it look different depending on whether you are on A or B.
7. If you want, you can have a separate block for the exposed filters, that you also add via the blockreference.
8. Use [Display suite](http://drupal.org/project/ds) or some other way to arrange the different blocks on the page.

The benefit of block reference + ds over theme regions is that you don't spam your theme regions with one-page-only blocks.

Comment: Boy... that's ugly.  I'm wondering if it would make sense to use the ajax views API and just do it in code.  I'm using Display Suite.  I'd rather write a cleaner solution and hand it off or post it in sandbox.  Can you tell me where I should start?

Comment: And still I get the bounty? I think I can come up with something better :) The block reference is still my favorite solution, but for other reasons than your requirements. So it might be distracting.

Comment: I generally find nodes easier to work with than page views.

Comment: Yeah... is there no way to signal the nodes to render using another view mode, defined by DS?  Is there a way to do it via AJAX?

Comment: Ah.. the ajax is important to you? Having the views on different urls is not an option?

Comment: Well, I figured it's easy enough to create an AJAX link and have a handler for it, and go from there.  It would be preferable to not care about the URL arguments, and just set a context and on the re-render, have the nodes figure out what context is set and re-render for that view mode.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11486/discussion-between-vintorg-and-donquixote)

Answer (score 1):

Just an idea and I might be mis-understanding what you need here but could you create multiple views, one for each view you need, expose the filters on them and then combine all these views with the [quicktabs module?](https://drupal.org/project/quicktabs)

Comment: The issue is it can't be part of the exposed block of filters, because the filters need to be on the left, and the view mode toggle at the top right somewhere. As I understand it, that can't be done because that would break up the form element.

Comment: yeah my bad, I was mistaken about what you were trying to do. Dont know about the toggling of views modes but [better exposed filters](https://drupal.org/project/better_exposed_filters) might help with the other part. which isnt what you asked but....

Comment: Yeah, I think I am going to try Better Exposed Filters.  I just need to figure out this view modes thing.  If I have to do it in code, that's fine, I just need someone to point me in the right direction.

Comment: I have just been looking into Display Suite and in the configuration page of Display suite extras (admin/structure/ds/list/extras) under the Other tab there is a "View Mode Switcher" check box. Could this help?

Comment: not sure... I couldn't figure out what that was for...  I'm going to look further...

Comment: when you say it can't be bound with the exposed filters do you mean that the filter you set on one page carries through onto the other or that each view has individual filters?

Comment: I mean, with filters (as I understand it), they are within a form element. So, if I were to include the view mode icon with the exposed form, it would have to be within that form element.  The issue is you can't break up a form element, where part of the form is in a sidebar, for example, and the view mode toggle is in the content, or another sidebar, etc.  So, if I want filters on my right sidebar, and the toggle icon at the top left of the page, I can't do it within an exposed form.

Answer (score 1):

So, it seems the general idea will be to have multiple views displays, and something to switch between those views displays.

The problem seems to be

1. How to create the switcher.
2. How to display the switcher in the intended location next to the exposed filters.

One solution could be hook_form_views_exposed_form_alter() to sneak the switcher into the form.

EDIT:
Another solution can be to put the switcher as custom html in the View header. Or you can write your own Views header plugin to have it reusable.

Comment: No.  The switcher can be located anywhere.  I can render the switcher.  The requirement is it can't be bound with the exposed filters.

Answer (score 0):

What about creating a custom select that appends arguments to the current url, and then implementing [hook_entity_view_mode_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_entity_view_mode_alter/7) and checking the paths?

```
function mymodule_entity_view_mode_alter(&$view_mode, $context) {
  if ($context['entity_type'] == 'node') {
    if (arg(0) == 'myview' && arg(1) == 'mode' && arg(2) == 'custom') {
      $view_mode = 'custom_view_mode';
    }
  }
}
```

There must be a cleaner way to do this. But this should work.